# JFileChooser making file name uneducable in showDialog box

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser, showdialog

I am working on an assignment that uses JFileChooser to allow a user to select a file and it will copy that file into whatever folder the user selects.  I was able to get the programming to automatically copy which ever file the user selects as a file with the same name and a .bak extension.

What I'd like to do is allow the user to select a destination folder for the file to be copied to and instead of using showSaveDialog, I found I could use showDialog and set everything to directories only.  **However, I was wondering if there is a way to get rid of the area where it allows the user to create a file name?  Or set it as uneditable? I changed it to showOpenDialog but that makes the user select a file and I couldn't find a way to make that directories only**

Thanks for any help!  I will post all my code since its a small program in case you want to see other parts and I will put the code in question in between ***'s.

```
public class CopyFile extends JFrame{

private JFileChooser fc;
private JButton copyButton;
private JButton chooseFileButton;
private JButton destinationButton;
private File workingDirectory;
private JLabel sourceLabel;
private JTextArea displayCopyText;
private JLabel destinationLabel;
private JTextField sourceText;
private JLabel copyText;
private JTextField destinationText;

public static void main(String [] args) {
    CopyFile go = new CopyFile();
    go.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    go.setResizable(false);
    go.setSize(500, 150);
    go.setVisible(true);
}

public CopyFile() {
    super("Copy a text file");
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    fc = new JFileChooser();

    //Open dialog box inside project folder to make easier to find files
    workingDirectory = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
    fc.setCurrentDirectory(workingDirectory);
    //create labels and buttons for window
    chooseFileButton = new JButton("CHOOSE SOURCE FILE");
    destinationButton = new JButton("DESTINATION FOLDER");
    copyButton = new JButton("COPY FILE");      
    sourceLabel = new JLabel("SOURCE FILE: ", JLabel.CENTER);
    sourceText = new JTextField(15);
    sourceText.setEditable(false);
    destinationText = new JTextField(15);
    destinationText.setEditable(false); 
    destinationLabel = new JLabel("DESTINATION:", JLabel.CENTER);
    //JScrollPane SP = new JScrollPane();       
    displayCopyText = new JTextArea();
    displayCopyText.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 50));
    displayCopyText.setRows(2);
    displayCopyText.setLineWrap(true);
    displayCopyText.setWrapStyleWord(true);
    displayCopyText.setEditable(false);     

    //add everything to JFrame  
    add(sourceLabel);
    add(sourceText);
    add(chooseFileButton);  
    add(destinationLabel);
    add(destinationText);
    add(destinationButton);
    //add(copyText);
    add(displayCopyText);
    add(copyButton);

    //Create TheHandler object to add action listeners for the buttons.
    TheHandler handler = new TheHandler();
    chooseFileButton.addActionListener(handler);
    destinationButton.addActionListener(handler);
    copyButton.addActionListener(handler);
}

//Inner class to create action listeners    
private class TheHandler implements ActionListener {
    private File selectedDestinationFile;
    private File selectedSourceFile;
    private int returnVal;

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {

    //Selecting a source file and displaying what the user is doing.
        if(event.getSource() == chooseFileButton) {     
            returnVal = fc.showOpenDialog(null);
            //Set the path for the source file. 
            if(returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {  
                selectedSourceFile = fc.getSelectedFile();
                sourceText.setText(selectedSourceFile.getName());   
            }       
        }//end if
    **********************************************************************************              
        //Handle destination button.
        if(event.getSource() == destinationButton) {
            fc.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
            fc.setDialogTitle("CHOOSE A FOLDER ONLY, NO NEED TO NAME THE FILE TO BE COPIED.");

            //I changed below from a showSaveDialog and played around with it with no luck.
            returnVal = fc.showDialog(null, "Choose Destination");
            if(returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                selectedDestinationFile = fc.getSelectedFile();
                destinationText.setText(fc.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath());
            }               
        }//end if
    **********************************************************************************

        //Handle copy button
        if(event.getSource() == copyButton) {
            /*
            Path sourcePath = selectedSourceFile.toPath();
            Path destinationPath = selectedDestinationFile.toPath();        
            try {
                Files.copy(sourcePath,  destinationPath);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }   */

            String name = selectedSourceFile.getName();
            name = selectedSourceFile.getName().substring(0,  name.lastIndexOf(".")) + ".bak";
            File destinationFile = new File(selectedDestinationFile.getParentFile(), name);
            destinationText.setText(name);  
            try {
                Files.copy(selectedSourceFile.toPath(), destinationFile.toPath());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            if(returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {      
                displayCopyText.append("SUCCESSFULLY COPIED:\n" 
                                + selectedSourceFile.getName() + " ===>> " + name); 
            }
            else {
                displayCopyText.append("COPY WAS CANCELED BY USER.\n");
            }   
        }//end if

    }//end actionPerformed      
}//end TheHandler class
}//end class
```

Comment: I think the short answer is no.  For ever reason you want to restrict the user, you should be checking the return result any way, looking for a `null` result and a invalid result (`!file.exists() || !file.isDirectory()`) anyway

Comment: The JFileChooser class has a constant 'DIRECTORIES_ONLY' which maybe use with the fileSelectionMode method.   or fc.fileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);

Comment: Well the assignment was to automatically copy a file into a .bak file with the same name.  I wanted the user to be able to save said file in any directory they wanted, but if they add a file name in there it is completely pointless since the program uses the source file name and adds a .bak to it.  I just wasn't sure if there was a different dialog box I was missing or a way to customize the showDialog to get rid of the place to enter a file name.  I'm not sure what you mean by the last part there....should I check for those for the source file also?

Comment: The destination shouldn't make a difference because even if the user chooses a file it'll just copy a .bak inside the folder of the file they selected

Comment: Hey cliff, thank you but, I am using the DIRECTORIES_ONLY.   It's not a huge deal because the program automatically creates a .bak with the same name as the source file, I just was trying to make it less confusing for the user by eliminating the option for them to enter a file name.

Comment: Well then you might want to goto the abstract FileSystemView and build your own dialog out of it.

Comment: Ok cool, thanks Cliff, I'll look into that.